# Execute Markov chains with tree-structured state in parallel with JAX

Tags: python, markov-chains, jax

I have a Markov chain function implemented in JAX that advances the chain from state `s -> s'` based on some training data (`X_train`).

```py
def step(state: dict, key, X_train) -> dict:
    new_state = advance(state, key, X_train)
    return new_state
```

Here, `state` is a fairly complicated tree-structured `dict` of array's that was generated by [Haiku](https://github.com/deepmind/dm-haiku). For example,

```py
state = {
    'layer1': {
        'weights': array(...),
        'bias': array(...),
    },
    'layer2': {
        'weights': array(...),
        'bias': array(...),
    },
}
```

I would like to run multiple Markov chains, with different states, in parallel. At first glance, [jax.vmap](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.vmap.html) function looks like a good candidate. However, `state` is not an array but a (tree-structured) `dict`.

What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: btw i don't believe `vmap` does use/guarantee parallelism. `pmap` does, but I'm not sure if you can pass it a `dict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use `vmap` for any [pytree](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytrees.html). But this is how you should construct it:

```
states = {'layer1':{'weights':jnp.array([[1, -2, 3],
                                         [4, 5, 6]])},
          'layer2':{'weights':jnp.array([[1, .2, 3],
                                         [.4, 5, 6]])}}
```

So in your first run, your weights will be `[1, -2, 3]` and `[1, .2, 3]` for layer1 and layer2 respectively (second run will be `[4, 5, 6]` and `[.4, 5, 6]`). But markov chain should be handled by [jax.lax.scan](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html). And you could use [jit compilation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/02-jitting.html) to speed things up. Here is a trivial example. In each step chain calculates the following:

[image]

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp 
from functools import partial

@jax.jit
def step(carry, k):
    # this function runs a single step in the chain
    # X_train dim:(3,3)
    # w1 dim: (1,3)
    # w2 dim: (3,1)
    # X_new = log(Relu(w1@X_old)@w2) + e
    # e~Normal(0, 1)
    
    state, X_train, rng = carry
    rng, rng_input = jax.random.split(rng)
    e = jax.random.normal(rng) # generate pseudorandom
    w1 = state['layer1']['weights'] # it is a column vector
    w2 = state['layer2']['weights'][None, :] # make it a row vector
    
    X_train = jax.nn.relu(w1@X_train)[:, None]+1
    X_train = jnp.log(X_train@w2)
    X_train = X_train + e
    
    return [state, X_train, rng], e

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums = 3)
def fi(state, X_train, key, number_of_steps):
    rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(key)
    carry = [state, X_train, rng]
    carry, random_normals = jax.lax.scan(step, carry, xs = jnp.arange(number_of_steps))
    state, X, rng = carry
    return X

X_train = jnp.array([[1., -1., 0.5],
                     [1., 1, 2.],
                     [4, 2, 0.1]])

states = {'layer1':{'weights':jnp.array([[1, -2, 3],
                                         [4, 5, 6]])},
          'layer2':{'weights':jnp.array([[1, .2, 3],
                                         [.4, 5, 6]])}}

vmap_fi = jax.vmap(fi, (0, None, None, None)) # only map on first argument axis 0

key = 42 # random seed
number_of_steps = 100 # chain runs 100 steps

last_states = vmap_fi(states, X_train, key, number_of_steps)
print(last_states)
```

`Output:`

```
[[[ 1.8478627   0.23842478  2.946475  ]
  [ 1.3278859  -0.28155205  2.4264982 ]
  [ 2.0921988   0.48276085  3.1908112 ]]

 [[ 2.9374144   5.4631433   5.645465  ]
  [ 3.4333894   5.959118    6.1414394 ]
  [ 3.4612248   5.9869533   6.169275  ]]]
```

In this example, you could make states dictionaries more complicated. You just need to parallelize on their `0`th axis.

Comment: Great thanks for this nice solution. Actually, I wanted to keep track of `state`.  But it seems that `fi(...)` works equally well with `jax.vmap` when I `return state`  instead of `return X`.

Comment: @Hylke Yes. `state`, `X` and `rng` are carried in scan. You could also modify `state` in the `scan` function. For this example, I only updated the `X` and returned it for the `fi` function.